# JQueryUI: Button inside a draggable div not working when div is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

First post on StackOverflow.

I tried to resume the issue in the title, and I made a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gBBcj/

The html generated seems correct, but the button in the dragged div does not work.
I even tried to redefine it as a .button(), but with no success.

Thanks for your help!

```
$(".box").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
$("#left").droppable({
    accept: '.box',
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        $(this).append('<div class="box"></div>');
        var droppedBox = $(this).children().last();
        $(droppedBox).html(ui.helper.html());
    }
});
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot without more of the code, but this could be a z-index issue. Try setting the z-index:99999 in the .myButton class

Comment: Thanks Brad. I posted all of the code. The button is visible and clickable, but not responding. Taking its z-index up didn't change the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Read [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

---

```
$(".container").on('click', '.myButton', function () {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5aKhL/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Tushar! It works like a charm. And I will read about Event Delegation :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `click()` binding applies to the elements that exists at the time when you first attach it. It does not apply for the newly added elements.

Use `on("click")` method to attach the click event, as in Tushar Gupta's answer. It attaches a delegate to the container that will handle the "click" of the newly added elements.

Comment: ...and this answers my question: "Why did it work out of the box in the left pane and why do I have to bind it when I move it to the right pane?"
Thank you!